# Artificial intelligence methods in mathematics

Tags: computer-science, education, philosophy, meta-math, metalogic

Are there aritficial intelligence methods in mathematics, automatic theorem discovery and proving? Google gives results in the opposite direction - mathematical methods of AI.

Are there applications of neural networks (connection science - neuro-symbolic computation), hypercomputation and cognitive architectures (like SOAR) into the automatic theorem discovery and proving? There is vast literature about symbolic computation (Elsevier has journal about this) but it is limited endeavor due to the Goedel incompleteness theorems. So - methods that more closely model human reasoning can be of help for automatisation of mathematical discoveries.

Comment: *when-will-the-humans-become-obsolete*-question, how adorable... I think, the main problem is that we cannot even *represent* the math *that we already have* in such a way that computers can work with it. There are a few theorem proof assistants which try to make the representation of mathematical theorems in computers possible / less painful, but this by itself is already difficult enough. What do you want to search for, if you cannot even represent the search-space properly? However, I think that the emergence of more sophisticated proof strategies is inevitable in the long run.

Comment: There are logics that can represent emotions, adaptable - everyday-reasoning style inference and they are meant for smart homes, robotics. Discovery of new algorithm or theorem usually is creative act that should be approached in similar fashion.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin "when-will-the-humans-become-obsolete-question, how adorable..." It's almost like you think you're an expert or something. It'd be adorable if you were, because that'd just make your commentary surprisingly lacking in good reference material to your *opinions*

Comment: I apologize if my previous comment appeared overly "pompous", I should have added a smiley or sth.. @reference material: essentially, every google-query starting with "automatic theorem prover" / "Coq" / "Isabelle" and ending with "Data mining"/"Machine learning" delivers bunch of papers that answer the question affirmatively: yes, of course, someone, somewhere clamped some ML-algos to theorem provers. But still, both ML and theorem provers have a long way to go until they can perform "creative acts". All this is not relevant however, if the OP wanted to ask specifically about Mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

Just some pointers to the development of the field - there is formalized mathematics branch with the de Gryuter journal "Formalized Mathematics". There is univalent foundation and homotopical type theory as new foundation and formalization of mathematics. Coq and Agda are practical proof assistants in this field. There is also Mizra system.

The question remains - can all this be used for discovery of new theorems and not for just checking of existing theorems. Maybe discovery cycle goes - probabilistic generation of statement in the formal language and subsequent proof or rejection by the prood assistant?